# Why are math formulas for pure numbers often applicable for physics?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, mathematics, si-units

Why are math formulas for pure numbers often applicable for physics (e.g., calculus formulas like divergence thereom, differentiation of sin)? Why is mathematics, which deals with abstract entities and man-made systems of rules, so successful at describing the real world.

This is a problem about relationship of math and physics.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis#Dimensional_homogeneity).

Comment: Why is English grammar suitable for describing animals, chemistry, physics, psychology etc? Why are your hands ok for building a boat, writing and so on? Math is a tool, like English, Chinese, Italian or the ability to use your hands. Note: exactly like English and your hands, math is also used in several fields, not only physics, and can have different purposes: numerical estimates, statistical inference, topology, arithmetic, logic...

Comment: regarding the $1 kg+ 1 m$: consider $a b+ c d$, you can not simplify this expression further. Consider $a b+ c b=(a +c) b$. Now imagine $b=m$, $d=kg$. Dimensions should be treated as arithmetic entities. But not only, they also have a meaning attached: since we can not (or, better, there is no need to do so) provide meaning to $m+kg$, this expression never appears in any physical calculation that has a meaning (unless you provide $+$ with a new meaning, e.g: 1 orange + 2 apples = 3 pieces of fruit... but how to do that for $kg$ and $m$ so that it makes sense and it's useful?).

Comment: See also [The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Mathematics in the Natural Sciences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unreasonable_Effectiveness_of_Mathematics_in_the_Natural_Sciences) by E. Wigner